# Call do_action using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an AJAX function that sends information to the `userpro_ajax_url` after successfully logging in through Facebook.

I am trying to get the success block to run a `do_action` function using

```
<?php 
ob_start();  
do_action('userpro_social_login', <email needs to go here>);
ob_clean();
?>
```

Right now if I pass the email address manually it works fine, however the only way I can get the email dynamically is through the current response which is in JavaScript.

The full function is:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name,gender', function(response) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: userpro_ajax_url,
        data: "action=userpro_fbconnect&id="+response.id+"&username="+response.username+"&first_name="+response.first_name+"&last_name="+response.last_name+"&gender="+response.gender+"&email="+response.email+"&name="+response.name+"&link="+response.link+"&profilepicture="+encodeURIComponent(profilepicture)+"&redirect="+redirect,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(data){
            userpro_end_load( form );
            <?php 
            ob_start();  
            do_action('userpro_social_login', );
            ob_clean();
            ?>
            /* custom message */
            if (data.custom_message){
                form.parents('.userpro').find('.userpro-body').prepend( data.custom_message );
            }
            /* redirect after form */
            if (data.redirect_uri){
                if (data.redirect_uri =='refresh') {
                    //document.location.href=jQuery(location).attr('href');
                } else {
                    //document.location.href=data.redirect_uri;
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Something wrong happened.');
        }
    });
});
```

I tried running the php action using:

```
jQuery(document).trigger('userpro_social_login', response.email);
```

Neither of these work... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: lol didn't see that coming executing php from js

Comment: I never thought I'll need to do that as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your php function `userpro_fbconnect` trigger the code there or create another ajax request after this one is done

Comment: Thanks Madalin, I could pass the trigger into that end point, however if that plugin ever gets updated it will break this functionality.

Comment: then do another ajax request

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm looking into doing right now, I think that should work fine :) once it works, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute `PHP` code from your `JS` and vise versa. But the following may help you:

```
<?php
   // Some php code goes here...
?>
<script>
   // JS code...
   ob_start();                                                                    
   do_action('userpro_social_login', <?php <email needs to go here> ?>);
   ob_clean();
</script>
```

And if you want to execute a method from your `JS`, and that method in defined using `PHP`, and it to the global scope, then simply call it from JS `my_global_method()`

I hope that helps fixing your problem.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, you got the gist of it, and I do use the php prior to the JS similar to what you pointed out, however, I am not able to pull the e-mail information from the php side since it is coming back from FB through the API call.

Comment: @Yohio Welcome, and accept the answer if it's working with you!

Comment: i don't understand your answer